# Sort list of objects in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build page that shows all selected movies depending on genre,
with    $.post

If genre is not selected page should show all movies.It is default selection.

This is Controller code:

```
public class BrowseController : Controller
{
    private MovieContext context = new MovieContext();
    // GET: Browse
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Genres = context.Genre.ToList();
        IEnumerable<Movie> mov = TempData["movies"] as IEnumerable<Movie>;
        if (mov == null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Movie> movies = context.Movies.ToList();
            return View(movies);
        }

        return View(mov);
    }
    [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Index(int id = -1)
    {
        IEnumerable<Movie> model;
        if (id != -1)
        {
            model = context.Movies.Where(x => x.GenreId == id);
        }
        else
        {
            model = context.Movies.ToList();
        }
        ViewBag.Genres = context.Genre.ToList();
        TempData["movies"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("", "Browse");
    }
}
```

And this is the view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Movies.Models.Movie>
@using Movies.Models
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
var Movie = Model.FirstOrDefault();
List<Genre> Genres = ViewBag.Genres;
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Movie.GenreId, new SelectList(Genres, "Id", 
"Name"), "")
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
    </th>
    <th>
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
@section Scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>


    $('select#Movie_GenreId').on('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).find(':selected').val();

        var url = "/Browse/Index";

        $.post(url, { id: value });

    });
</script>
```

}

I checked Chrome Debugging tool and Network tab and I see in Preview tab of response that there are no errors and Get Browse/Index action is returning expected results but I don't see them in View. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a `POST` request , but you don't handle the response. For instance, you forget to update the `DOM` structure.

For doing this, you have to attach a `callback` function to the returned response.

```
$.post(url, { id: value },function(response){
     //here is request response
});
```

Also, when you use `AJAX`, the purpose is to update DOM without refresh page to see the updates.

The solution is to return a `JSON` object with all the informations and then, handle them in the `callback` function of `$.post` method.

Comment: I changed POST Index to return Json and wrote function that should handle response but I'm not sure how to update DOM. Any suggestion or articles I could read for example?

Comment: Yes, you should iterate the list received using forEach method..and use jquery `append` method in order to update the DOM

Comment: Can u tell me why I'm unable to get results in the same view(index), when i change selection on select list and $.post send selected value to Post Index Action and that Action sends filtered results to Get Index Action ?

Comment: If you follow my advices you should get the response,